# Cython: Simple Matrix summation doesn't scale for large matrices (is it a cache issue?)

Tags: performance, loops, caching, parallel-processing, cython

I'm a Cython beginner and want to experiment a little with parallel computing. Therefore, I created a simple function which just sums up to matrices A & B and saves the result to a third one C.

It works as expected and for small matrix dimensions N the scaling is also almost linear, but when I increase the matrix size over a certain amount the scaling breaks down.

I assume that this is caused by the matrices do not fit into the CPUs cache anymore, but I don't know how to solve this problem. Or is there no solution because the calculation is not CPU intensive enough?
Any hints are welcome! Thank you so much.
Mohinder

```
from cython.parallel cimport prange

cdef cpu_add(float[:,:] a, float[:,:] b, float[:,:] c, int n_threads):
    cdef int i,j
    for i in prange(a.shape[0], schedule='static', nogil=True, num_threads=n_threads):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            c[i,j] = a[i,j] + b[i,j]
```

Comment: To fit in L1 cache, use 32x32 sub-matrix multiplications. To fit in registers, use 2x2,4x4 sub-matrix multiplications too. Cache tiling, register tiling.